# Automação Selenium Webdriver com Python - problema para interagir

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automatização

Bom dia!

Estou fazendo uma automação web, é minha primeira automação e estou travado nos finalmente dele, a onde devo fazer download de uns xml.

O Webdriver não está conseguindo interagir com uma aba que abre para o download.

```
ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 61
     57 # Baixar Selecionados
     58 navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="ctl00"]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]').click()
---> 61 navegador.find_element('xpath', '//*[@id="MainContent_cphMainContent_advancedsearch_DownloadXml_btnDownloadSelected"]').click()
```

Esse é o codigo xpath que estou tentando interagir:

```
[@id="MainContent_cphMainContent_advancedsearch_DownloadXml_btnDownloadSelected"]
```

Comment: quando abre essa nova "aba" voce esta avisando a automação que voce quer navegar nessa nova aba? seria algo parecido com isso  driver.switch_to.window(1)